# Get HTML Source of WebElement in Selenium WebDriverJS

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

There is a similar question out there (an older one in Python) but this one has to do with JS.  Testing using Selenium in a NodeJS, Mocha environment.  What I'd like to do is click on a Bootstrap dropdown and check the HTML to look for changes.  I've tried the following:

```
test.it('should click on all header links',
function() {
    var elem = driver.findElement(By.id('Profile'));
    console.log(elem.getAttribute('innerHTML'));
    console.log(elem.getInnerHtml());
});
```

Both calls return the same thing.

```
{ then: [Function: then],
  cancel: [Function: cancel],
  isPending: [Function: isPending] }
```

I plan to feed the HTML into cheerio so i can check for structure changes.  Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to retrieve the HTML as a string by doing the following.

```
driver.findElement(By.id('Profile')).getAttribute("innerHTML").then(function(profile) {
    console.log(profile);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the inner HTML with:

```
  element.getAttribute('innerHTML').then(function (html) {          
                console.log(html)
            })
```